# App Engine Flex failed to configure resources

Tags: google-app-engine

During last 2 days we stuck with deployment problem.
App deployed perfectly before. We have not introduced any change to `app.yaml`.

Doing usual stuff like `gcloud app deploy app.yaml`

```
service: subscriber
runtime: nodejs
env: flex

env_variables:
  SCRIPT: subscriber.js
  LOG_LEVEL: info

health_check:
  enable_health_check: false

resources:
  memory_gb: 4

automatic_scaling:
  min_num_instances: 1
  max_num_instances: 40
  cpu_utilization:
    target_utilization: 0.75
```

Build goes as usually but at the end it fails with error:

```
34b3438ad618: Layer already exists
de5e96f3b52d: Layer already exists
21df82f90a72: Layer already exists
0529bceacd9f: Layer already exists
3578a2f7453e: Pushed
94aa0c608f65: Pushed
latest: digest: sha256:3addb3a35b43dc5c45ebc86ad10c7f8c7b4408c781095fd819bd94ac8d7b497b size: 2417
DONE
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Updating service [subscriber] (this may take several minutes)...failed.                                                                                                                                                        
ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [13] App Engine Flex failed to configure resources.
```

Gcloud version:

```
gcloud version
Google Cloud SDK 189.0.0
alpha 2017.09.15
beta 2017.09.15
bq 2.0.29
core 2018.02.12
gcloud 
gsutil 4.28
kubectl
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may have been correlated with a recent release related to the `enable_health_check: false` parameter for applications where `split_health_checks` are enabled.

Could you try to deploy with `enable_health_check: true` or run the [command](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/configuring-your-app-with-app-yaml#legacy_health_checks):

`gcloud app update --no-split-health-checks`?

Comment: Removed this part from app config: ```-health_check:
-  enable_health_check: false```

Answer (score 1):

According to the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/configuring-your-app-with-app-yaml#health_checks):

> ... 
>   [Updated health checks](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/configuring-your-app-with-app-yaml#updated_health_checks) are more fine-grained and allow you to use
>   separate checks to confirm that your App Engine instance is running
>   (live) and ready to serve content (ready). These health checks are
>   **enabled by default**.

It basically means that there is no need to include `enable_health_check: False`. Just omit these two lines if you don't want to use legacy health checks.

On the other hand, if you want to use [legacy health checks](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/configuring-your-app-with-app-yaml#legacy_health_checks), run the command:

`gcloud app update --no-split-health-checks`

and add a health check section to your configuration file:

```
health_check:
  enable_health_check: True

  check_interval_sec: 5

  timeout_sec: 4
  unhealthy_threshold: 2
  healthy_threshold: 2
```